# Getting the checksum of a file through vsFTPd

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm making a script for automatically downloading a backup of files from a local server. There are a lot of files, so to avoid downloading unchanged files, I want to compare the remote file hash to the local file hash before downloading anything. However, I am unable to use the HASH command on my vsFTPd server.

I assume this means that the HASH command is somehow disabled or disallowed, but hours of googling have yet to tell me how to enable it, or if vsFTPd supports the HASH command at all.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Alternatively, if vsFTPd doesn't support the HASH command, is there another FTP server for Ubuntu that I can use?

Here is an example:

```
erlend@server:~$ ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (localhost:erlend): erlend
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 EPRT command successful. Consider using EPSV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-r--r--    1 1002     1002       102653 Oct 05 08:19 myfile.zip
226 Directory send OK.
```

But when I try to get the file hash, I get:

```
ftp> HASH  myfile.zip
?Invalid command
```

Tried with no argument (and lowercase!) as suggested in comments:

```
ftp> hash
Hash mark printing off.
ftp> hash
Hash mark printing on (1024 bytes/hash mark).
ftp> hash 1
Hash mark printing on (1 bytes/hash mark).
ftp> hash 2
Hash mark printing on (2 bytes/hash mark).
ftp> hash
Hash mark printing off.
ftp> hash myfile.zip
Hash mark printing off.
```

Comment: Might sound stupid, but what happens if you run `hash` on its own, with no argument?

Comment: Please have a look at this thread: https://serverfault.com/a/853365
It might help.

Comment: @LewisSmith: I tried, edited the results into the question. BhavinJoshi: Thanks, according to that answer, it looks like it's not possible. My research so far indicates the same, but I'm still hoping to be proven wrong. Why isn't this a standard? Wouldn't there be a lot of use cases for not downloading a file if it is exactly the same?

Comment: On the server, run a daily cron job that hashes all files in a directory and stores the results in `hashlist`. Download `hashlist` and compare it to your local hash values to see which files have changed?

Comment: When using a SFTP client like Filezilla, when you try to dowload a particular file, it warns and shows a dialog box with some options. One of them is 'Download only if the file size is different'. The other one is 'Download only if source file is newer' and there are few others. I guess, you may not need to use hash if it is not supported.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Thanks, yes, that seems to be the easiest way of doing this properly.

Comment: @BhavinJoshi: Thanks, that is one way to do it, but the FileZilla checks are based on size and/or time, and neither are 100% guaranteed to tell me that the files are indeed identical, so I would prefer to use a hashing function. (The time property could be safe enough, but my receiving script is on a Windows machine, on which I have experienced issues with file times before.)

Comment: Yes, if the platforms are different, especially windows, you need to be extra careful. For now, vsFTPd does not support hash. So I advise you to look for other options.

Comment: Unless better ideas come along, I'll write an answer after work.

Comment: Go ahead, @WinEunuuchs2Unix, but don't spend any time on an actual script, it's already done. :)

Comment: @ErlendD. I didn't spend much time as I already had a script written which I've used for another project. So I repurposed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server have a cron job that runs daily in `/etc/cron.daily`. No special `crontab` magic needs to be done. Simply but an executable script there.

Here is one I have handy already for calculating hash sums on files:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

    md5sum \
        install.sh \
        eyesome.sh \
        eyesome-cfg.sh \
        eyesome-src.sh \
        eyesome-sun.sh \
        wake-eyesome.sh \
        start-eyesome \
        daily-eyesome-sun \
        systemd-wake-eyesome \
        acpi-lid-eyesome.sh \
        acpi-lid-event-eyesome \
        eyesome-dbus.sh \
        > eyesome.md5
```

So you would download the file `eyesome.md5` to your remote machine.

```bash
$ cat eyesome.md5
2627fe73a1c99c1ec02a17002cf88dad  install.sh
62999343cd603c4bff70e890367739bb  eyesome.sh
c42766c412b31c45d814efea36c1021b  eyesome-cfg.sh
8e56b945b9173dee4cceecb1b111b28a  eyesome-src.sh
d70ca24ca2aea58b043d86e9bdd15c0e  eyesome-sun.sh
28b0fde9a98933fee0226c49350fdc6c  wake-eyesome.sh
712eff1f4ec14fbf04521674c32aa5b8  start-eyesome
0cdc4dbb0a383cd97f1e6d0744a6f8e4  daily-eyesome-sun
5a2abb831f31a7339270868ddd37f745  systemd-wake-eyesome
e06f195dcf254d65b4f8512d46e44458  acpi-lid-eyesome.sh
8ce2412bdb1bab4bca6e4921f9ae282b  acpi-lid-event-eyesome
54e3052f12ca33fc53e38b01d4dd05d6  eyesome-dbus.sh
```

**Note:** If your file names are prefixed with a path you may have to change it from the server's path to your local path with `sed`, `grep` or another utility.

Then run:

```bash
$ md5sum -c eyesome.md5
install.sh: OK
eyesome.sh: OK
eyesome-cfg.sh: OK
eyesome-src.sh: FAILED
eyesome-sun.sh: OK
wake-eyesome.sh: FAILED
start-eyesome: OK
daily-eyesome-sun: OK
systemd-wake-eyesome: OK
acpi-lid-eyesome.sh: OK
acpi-lid-event-eyesome: OK
eyesome-dbus.sh: OK
md5sum: WARNING: 2 computed checksums did NOT match
```

The files that fail (`eyesome-src.sh` and `wake-eyesome.sh`) you need to download.

Comment: The comments on the question seems to indicate that vsFTPd does not support file hashing, so although this answer is not a direct answer to the question, this is the method I will be using. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question about comparing HASH, however, is too long for a comment.

If you want to avoid downloading files twice, downloading files that have different modification time or different size should be enough in most situations. If this is the case, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/106365/237584) about using [lfpt](https://lftp.tech/lftp-man.html) will be useful.

It uses the `mirror` option to keep your FTP folder and local folders in sync downloading only the files that have changed.

From the [linked answer](https://serverfault.com/a/106365/237584) by GabrieleV:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash    
HOST="your.ftp.host.dom"
USER="username"
PASS="password"
FTPURL="ftp://$USER:$PASS@$HOST"
LCD="/path/of/your/local/dir"
RCD="/path/of/your/remote/dir"
#DELETE="--delete"
lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a;
open '$FTPURL';
lcd $LCD;
cd $RCD;
mirror --reverse \
       $DELETE \
       --verbose \
       --exclude-glob a-dir-to-exclude/ \
       --exclude-glob a-file-to-exclude \
       --exclude-glob a-file-group-to-exclude* \
       --exclude-glob other-files-to-exclude"
```

**Warning:** make sure that the target directory exists, otherwise the cd command will fail, so operation **including deleting trees of files**  will take place at wrong directory (root)!

Comment: Thank you! This also looks like a good alternative, but as I already have a dependency on both the client and the server I'm using, I won't be exploring lftp this time.